# Visual Basics - Delete multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete multiple rows in VBA for Excel using the macro code:

```
Sub sbDeleteARowMulti() 
Rows("1:3").Delete 
End Sub
```

However I would like to alter this so that I can delete more than one set of rows at once e.g. 1:200 and 404:1023 and 1230:1339 etc. Is there a simple way to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
Application.Union( _
    Rows("1:200"), _
    Rows("404:1023"), _
    Rows("1230:1339")).Delete
```

or

```
Range("1:200, 404:1023, 1230:1339").Delete
```

Comment: I just tried the second one and it works perfectly.  Thank you Alex K.